# Reduce AWS EBS volume size

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, amazon-ebs

I want to reduce the size of the EBS volume from 250GB to 100GB. I know it can't be done directly from the console. That's why I have tried few links like [Decrease the size of EBS volume in your EC2 instance](https://medium.com/@m.yunan.helmy/decrease-the-size-of-ebs-volume-in-your-ec2-instance-ea326e951bce) and [Amazon EBS volumes: How to Shrink ’em Down to Size](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/) which haven't helped me. May be this will work for plain data but in my case I have to do it on /opt which have installations and configuration.

Please let me know if it is possible to do, and how.

Comment: Why do you think a `/opt` mount will prevent the standard method, described in your links, from working? Have you actually tried it? Did you encounter an error?

Answer (score 2):

mount new volume to /opt2, copy all the files from /opt with rsync or something preserve the links etc. update your /etc/fstab and reboot.

if all good, umount the old volume from the ec2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Laurel and Jayesh Basically you guys have to follow following instructions:

1. First, Shut down the instance (MyInstance) to prevent any problem.
2. Create a new 6GIB EBS volume.
3. Mount the new volume (myVolume)
4. Copy data from the old volume to the new volume (myVolume)
   Use rysnc to copy from old volume to the new volume (myVolume) `sudo rsync -axv / /mnt/myVolume/.`
5. Wait until it’s finished. ✋
6. Install GRUB
7. Install grub on myVolume using command
8. Log out from the instance and shut it down.
9. Detach old volume and attach the new volume (myVolume) to /dev/xvda
10. Start instance, you see an instance is now running with 6GIB EBS volume size.

Reference: https://www.svastikkka.com/2021/04/create-custom-ami-with-default-6gib.html